# How to make the featured image without a fixed position?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I already know how to style the featured image and give it a class, but I don't want it to have a fixed position. Instead, I want it to have a custom position for every post (I set the position manually for every post). How possibly can I achieve that ?

Comment: Sample code will help us visualize what you want. Anyway, you could add `style` attribute to the featured image.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your post loop, to make as way you want :

```
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() )
the_post_thumbnail();
else
echo '<img src="' . trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ) . 'images/default-   thumbnail.png' . '" alt="" />';
?>
```